# imagemagick for extracting the fewest continuous clockwise external boundary points from black and white image

Tags: imagemagick

Are there sure-fire ways in imagemagick for

extracting the fewest continuous clockwise external boundary points (each outer vertex of the lines shown in example)

For example: from a black and white image like this?

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried and also what you expect as the correct *"answer"* for your input image. Or, are there 2 images here?

Comment: Imagemagick does not know clockwise vs counterclockwise in edge image.  Perhaps I do not understand what you are trying to extract. Please explain further or mark your diagram with what you want.